# PBS scheduler assigning same processor for an MPI program of 3 processors

Tags: mpi, pbs

I am doing MPI programming on a cluster with 8 nodes and each having a Intel Xeon hexcore processor. I need three processors for my mpi code.

I submit the job using qsub. When I check on which processors the job is running using "qstat -n" it says something like   cn004/0*3 .

So does this mean it is running it on only one processor ??

Because it is not speeding up than when I use a single processor(This is when the domain size is the same for both cases)

The script i use for submitting is as follows

```
#! /bin/bash
#PBS -o logfile.log
#PBS -e errorfile.err
#PBS -l cput=40:00:00
#PBS -lselect=1:ncpus=3:ngpus=3
#PBS -lplace=excl
cat $PBS_NODEFILE
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
mpicc -g -W -c -I /usr/local/cuda/include mpi1.c
mpicc -g -W mpi1.o -L /usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lOpenCL
mpirun -np 3 ./a.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "qstat -n" it says something like cn004/0*3.
>
> **Q:** So does this mean it is running it on only one processor ??

The short answer is "no". This does not mean that it runs on one processor.
"cn004/0*3" should be interpreted as "The job is allocated three cpu cores. And if we were to number the cores from 0 to 5 then the cores allocated would have numbers 0,1,and 2".

If another job were to run on the node it would receive the next three consecutive numbers "3,4, and 5". In the `qstat -n` output this would look like "cn004/3*3".

You use the directive `place=excl` to ensure that other jobs would not get the node, so essentially all the six cores are available.

Now for your second question:

> **Q:** it is not speeding up than when I use a single processor

In order to answer this question we need to know if the algorithm is parallelized correctly.

Comment: Unlike CUDA, the OpenCL compiler is part of the runtime environment, therefore one doesn't need an "OpenCL enabled" compiler backend for `mpicc`.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you, I was not sure about that.

Comment: Is there any way i can findout inside the program which "node" is the program running ? This is if I had given select=2